# $x^{1/n}$ vs $\log x$ where $x$ is very large

Tags: calculus

when $x$ is very large number, which is smaller?

$\log x$ vs $x^{1/n}$

$n$ might be very large natural number

Is $\lim_{x → ∞} x^{1/n} / \log x = ∞$  for all $n$?

Is $\log x$ too smaller than rational function?
Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you multiply x by some number, you end up multiplying $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ by a smaller number, but you only *add* a number to the logarithm. If x is increased exponentially (multiplying it by the same number over and over again), $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ will also increase exponentially, but the logarithm will only increase linearly.

The linear function may *start out* larger than the exponential, but on a large enough interval, the increasing exponential function *always* overtakes the increasing linear function.